# ¿Como insertar un enlace con Html por medio de PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estoy empezando a implementar de como recuperar o restablecer una contraseña olvidado por el usuario desde una app, ya tengo creado el formulario el cual se le pide al usuario que ingrese su contraseña y se le envía a su correo, en el archivo php en mensaje tengo dentro un html el cual quiero que solo tenga el enlace de la referencia haciendo clic en el texto, pero el detalle es que se me muestra toda la estructura de html al abrir el correo del destinatario.

**recuperarPass.php**

```
<?php

  include("conexion.php");

  $email = $_POST["email"];

  $statement=$mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM t_usuario WHERE email=?');
  $statement->bind_param("s",$email);


  if ($statement->execute()) {
    $results = $statement->get_result();

    if ($results->num_rows ==1) {
        
         $linkResetPass ="https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/passNuevo.php";
    
        $paraemail = $email;
        $titulo = "Recuperar contraseña";
        $mensaje ='
         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="es">
         <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
         <title>Recuperar tu contraseña</title>
         </head>
         <body>
         <h2>Favor de dar clic en el siguiente enlace para recuperar tu contrtaseña</h2>
         <a href='.$linkResetPass.'>Recuperar tu contraseña aqui</a>
         </body>
         </html>';

        $tuemail = "From: juaritoz82@gamil.com";

        if (mail($paraemail,$titulo,$mensaje,$tuemail)) {
           echo"1";
        }else {
           echo"2";
        }
    }else {
        echo"3";
    }
      
  }

 $mysql->close();
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente declara en los headers de tu email que es de tipo HTML

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

    include("conexion.php");

    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $statement= $mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM t_usuario WHERE email=?');
    $statement->bind_param( "s", $email );
    
    // Headers
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\b";
    $headers .= 'From: juaritoz82@gamil.com' . "\r\n";

    if ($statement->execute()) {

        $results = $statement->get_result();
        if ($results->num_rows ==1) {
        
            $linkResetPass ="https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/passNuevo.php";
    
                $paraemail = $email;
                $titulo = "Recuperar contraseña";
                $mensaje ='
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="es">
                    <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                    <title>Recuperar tu contraseña</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <h2>Favor de dar clic en el siguiente enlace para recuperar tu contrtaseña</h2>
                    <a href='.$linkResetPass.'>Recuperar tu contraseña aqui</a>
                    </body>
                    </html>';

                if ( mail( $paraemail, $titulo, $mensaje, $headers ) ) {
                
                    echo "1";
                
                } else {

                    echo "2";

                }
        
        } else {
            
            echo "3";

        }
      
    }

 $mysql->close();
```

Siendo

```
// Headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\b";
$headers .= 'From: juaritoz82@gamil.com' . "\r\n";
```

los headers de tu email y agregándolos al momento de ejecutar mail();

```
mail( $paraemail, $titulo, $mensaje, $headers )
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda ya la estructura de html ya no se muestra, solo el correo de quien envía no se muestra. user17223682 <user17223682@us-imm-node2b.000webhost.io>

Comment: Ya lo resolví, gracias amigo.